# validate all fields using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
           var validated = false;
            $('input').each(function(){
                if($(this).val() == ''){
                    alert("All fields are compulsory!");
                }else{
                    validated = true;
                }

            });

            if(validated == true){
                window.location.href = "#next";
            }
```

I have problem detecting and preventing the user to go to the next page if all fields are not filled. Above is the code I've tried, but it has a flaw.

Comment: Have you used it in a form?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your looping logic.

Your logic updates the `validated` flag as true even if 1 input has value, instead you need to update the initial value as true, then when the first item is found as invalid then you can stop the looping also as you have only a common message.

```
var validated = true;
$('input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        alert("All fields are compulsory!");
        validated = false;
        //stop the loop
        return false;
    }

});

if (validated == true) {
    window.location.href = "#next";
}
```